Types of Multi-GPU Training for a 70B model using Huggingface Trainer
In this discussion I have learnt that the Trainer class automatically handles multi-GPU training, we don’t have to do anything special if using the top-rated solution.
If I have a 70B LLM and load it with 16bits, it basically requires 140GB-ish VRAM. Obviously a single H100 or A800 with 80GB VRAM is not sufficient. Let's say I have 4 A800 GPUs with 320GB VRAM in total and I have loaded the 70B LLM for fine-tuning. The trainer can detect and use all 4 GPUs, but the question is, What type of Multi-GPU Training parallelism does trainer use when using the top-rated solution from ikirk?
Does trainer evenly distribute this 70b model layers across these 4 GPUs, or just distribute all layers to 2 GPUs (theoretically 2 A800 GPUs are sufficient for serving a 70B LLM which requires roughly 140GB VAM) and the rest 2 GPUs are only used for data processing?
Is there any way to config this to reach better GPU usage when using Huggingface Trainer and Accelerate library?
